# Why does the animation work only once, yet the other effects work with each click, as desired?

Tags: jquery, onclick, jquery-animate

I want the 'block' effects *and* the 'button rotation' to run *every* time the 'clickMe' button is clicked, but the rotation animation only runs once. Why?

It's supposed to be just a simple jQuery demo of having one button effect a div, whilst the said button rotates. I've tried to avoid my question but I just cannot get my head around this problem. Tried Chrome and Firefox. Thank you in advance.

```
$("#clickMe").click(function(){

    // This happens with each click... as I wish for all the code!
    $("#block1").fadeOut(2000);
    $("#block1").delay(6000).slideDown(3000);

    // This works only once, but I don't understand why.
    $(this).animate(
    {rotation: 360},
    {duration: 1000,
        step: function(now, fx){
            $(this).css({"transform": "rotate(" + now + "deg)"});
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The problem is** when rotate the element the `now` becomes `360` and this is the same value of rotation so it won't rotate again ..

**To solve this** .. Reset the animation's `rotation` after `rotation:360` to `rotation:0` by adding another `animation()`

```
.animate(
    {rotation: 0},
    {duration: 0,
     step: function(now, fx){
        ThisIt.css({"transform": "rotate(" + now + "deg)"});
     }
 });
```

**Demo**

```js
$("#clickMe").click(function(){
     var ThisIt = $(this);
    // This happens with each click... as I wish for all the code!
    $("#block1").fadeOut(2000);
    $("#block1").delay(6000).slideDown(3000);

    // This works only once, but I don't understand why.
    ThisIt.animate(
    {rotation: 360},
    {duration: 1000,
    step: function(now, fx){
        ThisIt.css({"transform": "rotate(" + now + "deg)"});
        }
    }).animate(
    {rotation: 0},
    {duration: 0,
    step: function(now, fx){
        ThisIt.css({"transform": "rotate(" + now + "deg)"});
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="clickMe">Click Me</button>
<button id="block1">BLOCK</button>
```

Comment: **Thank you** so much, Mohammed-Yousef. This has, of course, worked perfectly! I understand how the code is working now, and so it makes sense that the animation needed resetting back to zero degrees again. Great fix! ;-)